# Is it acceptable to modify Drupal's composer.json file?

Tags: 8, composer

Drupal adheres to the best-practice of [never modifying core](http://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core).

Drupal 8 has a composer.json file built into core, if you need to add a third-party library, should you modify composer.json, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can we re-open this discussion given that it's been two years since it was last discussed? I've read that in Drupal 8 RC1, one can now manage modules directly via `composer require` in the Drupal docroot. That's all well and good, but what if I need to do `composer require drupal/drupal-extension` which pulls in Behat, and subsequently modifies many things in D8 core's vendor directory? This is particularly a tricky question in Pantheon where apparently the repo root must be the Drupal docroot.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to consume Drupal 8 into your own `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "davidbarratt/mydrupalproject",
    "require": {
        "drupal/drupal": "8.*"
        "composer/installers": "1.*"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "drupal/drupal",
                "type": "drupal-core",
                "version": "8.0.0-dev",
                "source": {
                    "url": "http://git.drupal.org/project/drupal.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "8.x"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

There's a pull request to `composer/installers`will allow installation of `drupal-core` project types:
http://github.com/composer/installers/pull/38

Would love your input on the above pull request, as well as this other one in the queue that allows installation of modules/themes/profiles.

Another solution that currently works is the [Composer Manager](http://drupal.org/project/composer_manager) module, which facilitates `composer.json` use for modules. It's currently available for Drupal 7, and will be available for Drupal 8 once the Drupal 8 alpha releases are close.

Thanks a lot,
Rob

Comment: Would you like to update your answer. :)
https://www.drupal.org/node/2404989

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [Composer module](http://drupal.org/project/composer) that is a Drush wrapper to Composer. Your module can then supply its own composer file which Drush will use to download additional dependencies for your module -- or site if you use say at least 1 "custom" module for your drupal site.

I also recommend watching this Drupal8 / Composer seminar from DrupalCon Munich 2012:
http://munich2012.drupal.org/content/drupal-has-dependencies-lets-manage-them

Comment: Drush Composer is just a wrapper around Composer. If you use it to modify Drupal's Composer-based requirements, it will modify Drupal's root `composer.json` file. Also, the video for Munich 2012 is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

It is acceptable to use Composer the way it's supposed to be used. :-)

Edit:

This package exists to help you manage your Composer-based Drupal project: https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project

Comment: Do you have a citation?

Comment: I have this: `composer create-project drupal/drupal drupal_root ~8@dev --keep-vcs` `cd drupal_root` `composer require vendor/package ~1` ...decide you don't need that package... `git checkout -- composer.json` `composer update` And I'd like to keep that.

Comment: That still modifies the root composer.json file. You'd still have to merge your changes with Drupal's changes. Or worse, if someone doesn't update their composer file as their told, you could encounter major errors or critical security holes. How do you get around this?

Comment: You don't. You have to do those things. There is no automatic composer stuff for Drupal 8 at the moment, beyond any script you might make to do it.

Comment: If you have to merge changes with Drupal, isn't that exactly why you don't modify core?

Comment: Yes. And no. Drupal 8 was not designed with any of these concerns in mind, beyond using Composer during core development to manage dependencies.

Comment: well it hasn't been released yet...

Comment: If it had been designed with any other concerns in mind, this wouldn't be a question. :-)

Comment: Anyone wanting to follow along with the development of Drupal 8's use of Composer can look at this drupal.org issue and it's child issues: https://www.drupal.org/node/2002304